# Console.log in chrome dev tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to `console.log` things I wrote in chrome dev tools. Unfortunately chrome's console respond to my requests. Here is code:

`var loop = function(){ while (i<4) { console.log("it's me, MARIO"); i++; } }`

and here is my console respond.

```
var loop = function(){ while (i<4) { console.log("it's me, MARIO"); i++; } }
=> undefined
i = 0 // if loop works i should be 4 after calling loop();
=> 0
loop(); // we call loop.
=> undefined
i
=> 4 // so loop does work.
```

Comment: The function still returns undefined, as all functions do ?

Comment: Works for me. Do you have anything that would have disabled `console.log()`?

Comment: I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: Again, when running a function direcly in the console, the returned result is logged, and all functions return undefined by default ?

Comment: @adeneo Yes, but the `console.log()` call inside the loop should print and it doesn't.

Comment: Works just fine for me? Of course, I did set `i` to 0 first ?

Comment: Does a simple `console.log(1)` work? Can you try in a fresh blank Chrome page? It is possible that the page you are working on has overwritten the log function. Far fetched, but it could happen.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uwsqC/) the code is working (even without define the `i` variable).
Check that your filter was set to log:[image]